# Hide specific exports in the npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am new to creating npm packages.
I would not want users to be able to import everything from my package, such as the `Utils` class.

```
export class Utils implements IUtils {
  // ......
}
```

How do I avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the `exports` key in your `package.json`. When this is set, only the specified paths can be accessed from the module.

Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports

The way I usually do this is to create an `index.js` or `index.ts` and add that to the `exports`. Then, anything I want to expose publicly, I export via the index file.

For example:

```
// index.ts
export { MyPublicClass } from './MyPublicClass'
```

Comment: Additional question. If I want to re-export a module from npm module dependencies, so the user doesn't have to install this package to its dependencies? `export * from 'module'`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but in general that's fairly bad practice. If you must, probably best to export it as an object. Something like:
`import * as myLib from 'mylib';
export { myLib }`